# ORA-01407: cannot update ("SYSADM"."PS_N_CERTMOD_TAO4"."DATE_CHAR") to NULL Failed SQL stmt: /*UPDATE

Tags: peoplesoft

```
Error Message: ORA-01407: cannot update
("SYSADM"."PS_N_CERTMOD_TAO4"."DATE_CHAR") to NULL Failed SQL stmt: /*UPDATE
```

When i am generating the report it is saying NO Success in `Peoplesoft`.

Below is the code which for Update statement.

Please help me how to overcome from this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

```
UPDATE %Table(N_CERTMOD_TAO) TMP 
  SET TMP.DATE_CHAR = ( CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
 SELECT A.descr254 
  FROM PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A 
 WHERE A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
   AND A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
   AND A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
   AND A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
   AND A.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN ) THEN ( 
 SELECT A.descr254 
  FROM PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A 
 WHERE A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
   AND A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
   AND A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
   AND A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
   AND A.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN ) ELSE (CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
 SELECT A.descr254 
  FROM PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A 
 WHERE A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
   AND A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
   AND A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
   AND A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
   AND A.ACAD_PLAN = ' ') THEN ( 
 SELECT A.descr254 
  FROM PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A 
 WHERE A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
   AND A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
   AND A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
   AND A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
   AND A.ACAD_PLAN = ' ') ELSE ( CASE WHEN EXISTS ( 
 SELECT B.A_EXAM_SEM_DT 
  FROM PS_A_XM_WRES_DTT_P B 
 WHERE B.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
   AND B.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
   AND B.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
   AND B.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
   AND B.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN) THEN ( 
 SELECT TO_CHAR(B.A_EXAM_SEM_DT) 
  FROM PS_A_XM_WRES_DTT_P B 
 WHERE B.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
   AND B.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
   AND B.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
   AND B.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
   AND B.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN) ELSE ( 
 SELECT TO_CHAR(C.A_EXAM_SEM_DT) 
  FROM PS_A_EXAM_WRES_DTT C 
 WHERE C.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
   AND C.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
   AND C.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
   AND C.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG ) END ) END ) END)
```

Answer (score 1):

First part of correction is proposed by Jared.

I think C.A_EXAM_SEM_DT could be `null` as well, so you should change `TO_CHAR(C.A_EXAM_SEM_DT)` to `NVL(TO_CHAR(C.A_EXAM_SEM_DT), ' '`

Consider of simplifying the statement, something like

```
UPDATE %Table(N_CERTMOD_TAO) TMP
   SET TMP.DATE_CHAR =
       (select nvl(A.descr254, --no value? -->
                   nvl(AA.descr254, -- no value? -->
                       nvl(TO_CHAR(B.A_EXAM_SEM_DT), -- no value? -->
                           nvl(TO_CHAR(C.A_EXAM_SEM_DT), -- no value? -->
                           ' ')))) -- default value
          from dual D
          left outer join PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A
            on (A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION AND
               A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER AND
               A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM AND
               A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG AND
               A.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN)
          left outer join PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL AA
            on (AA.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION AND
               AA.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER AND
               AA.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM AND
               AA.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG AND AA.ACAD_PLAN = ' ')
          left outer join PS_A_XM_WRES_DTT_P B
            on (B.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION AND
               B.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER AND
               B.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM AND
               B.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG AND
               B.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN)
          left outer join PS_A_EXAM_WRES_DTT C
            on (C.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION AND
               C.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER AND
               C.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM AND
               C.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a final case condition so that if its going to be null it returns a ' ' instead.

```
UPDATE %Table(N_CERTMOD_TAO) TMP 
SET TMP.DATE_CHAR = ( CASE 
WHEN EXISTS( 
SELECT A.descr254 
FROM PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A 
WHERE A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
AND A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
AND A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
AND A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
AND A.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN ) 
THEN ( 
SELECT A.descr254 
FROM PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A 
WHERE A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
AND A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
AND A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
AND A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
AND A.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN ) 
ELSE (  CASE 
WHEN EXISTS( 
SELECT A.descr254 
FROM PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A 
WHERE A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
AND A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
AND A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
AND A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
AND A.ACAD_PLAN = ' ') 
THEN ( 
SELECT A.descr254 
FROM PS_N_CERTMONYR_DTL A 
WHERE A.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
AND A.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
AND A.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
AND A.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
AND A.ACAD_PLAN = ' ') 
ELSE ( CASE 
WHEN EXISTS ( 
SELECT B.A_EXAM_SEM_DT 
FROM PS_A_XM_WRES_DTT_P B   
WHERE B.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
AND B.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
AND B.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
AND B.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
AND B.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN) 
THEN ( 
SELECT TO_CHAR(B.A_EXAM_SEM_DT) 
FROM PS_A_XM_WRES_DTT_P B 
WHERE B.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
AND B.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
AND B.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
AND B.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG 
AND B.ACAD_PLAN = TMP.ACAD_PLAN) 
ELSE ( CASE
WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT TO_CHAR(C.A_EXAM_SEM_DT) 
FROM PS_A_EXAM_WRES_DTT C 
WHERE C.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
AND C.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
AND C.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
AND C.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG )
THEN (
SELECT TO_CHAR(C.A_EXAM_SEM_DT) 
FROM PS_A_EXAM_WRES_DTT C 
WHERE C.INSTITUTION = TMP.INSTITUTION 
AND C.ACAD_CAREER = TMP.ACAD_CAREER 
AND C.STRM = TMP.COMPLETION_TERM 
AND C.ACAD_PROG = TMP.ACAD_PROG )
ELSE
' '
END )   
END ) 
END ) 
END)
```

Comment: Hi Jared thanks for your answer even i added final statement 
find below the statement                                                                          "WHERE TMP.PROCESS_INSTANCE = %ProcessInstance"
i included this line after END) even though it is throwing an error.